# What is the significance of classical invariant theory (Hilbert)?

Tags: math-history, constructive-mathematics, invariant-theory

**Background**

I am writing a paper about David Hilbert's impact for my history of mathematics class. The [MacTutor Mathematics history website](http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/history/Biographies/Hilbert.html) says that,

> As we saw above, Hilbert's first work was on invariant theory and, in 1888, he proved his famous Basis Theorem.

and elaborating,

> He discovered a completely new approach which proved the finite basis
>   theorem for any number of variables but in an entirely abstract way.
>   Although he proved that a finite basis existed his methods did not
>   construct such a basis.

As I understand, some mathematicians of the time were uncomfortable with Hilbert's novel methods. He proved that a "basis" existed without ever showing any example of such a basis. Felix Klein later wrote to Hilbert,

> I do not doubt that this is the most important work on general algebra
>   that the 'Annalen' has ever published.

**Questions**

I have the following questions:

1. What is the significance of invariance theory on mathematics? What is the basic idea of invariance theory, and why is the Basis theorem important?
2. How impactful was Hilbert's new "abstract" approach to mathematics?

If you have an answer for (1) but not (2) or (2) but not (1), that is fine! I would appreciate any thoughs on the impact of Hilbert on mathematics.

Comment: I suggest you go back to your teacher and ask what methods and resources you were expected to use. The answer to "[what was the impact of] Hilbert's new abstract approach to mathematics" merits a book, not just a sentence or two. I see you have now been spoon-fed with a partial answer. I wish you well with the write up in your paper of Rene's accurate assessment of the impact as "immense".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intuitive meaning of invariant theory is it looks for properties invariant under linear coordinate changes. For example take a quadratic form
$$ax^2+bxy+cy^2$$ this factors as a product of two linear factors. Now these two factors could be equal or distinct. That is a property invariant under a linear change in the variables $x,y$. This is also determined by whether the discriminant $$b^2-4ac$$ is equal to zero or not. The discriminant (and its powers) are in fact the only invariant of a quadratic. Invariant of other higher order expressions would describe further more subtle properties, again properties not depending on the coordinate system.

One word describes Hilbert's influence: immense.

Comment: Does invariant theory prove especially useful for other areas of mathematics, or is it more of an investigation for its own sake?

Comment: Invariant theory has close ties to projective geometry, algebraic geometry and algebra. Its modern resurrection is a significant branch of algebraic geometry many of whose core ideas go back to Hilbert's further researches. Note also that the Nullstellensatz and the chain of syzygies (the two other staples of modern algebra) were also proved in the context of invariant theory.